# Find the number of rows executed from historical query

Tags: sql-server

I want to run a query on SQL server logs to get the date of the query execution the text of the query and the number of rows of the results.

I tried so far to use

```
 SELECT  dest.text,deqs.last_execution_time 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > '8/22/2017 00:00'
        AND dest.text LIKE '%WorldRecords2%';
```

But there is no rows

Any ideas????

Comment: Have you tested without this `dest.text LIKE '%WorldRecords2%'` condition?

Comment: `WorldRecords2` does this mean are you testing for number of rows